# Remote debugging from 64 bit Development system to 32 bit virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I have a Windows 7 64 Bit machine with Visual Studio 2010 Pro. On  this machine, I have a Vista Business 32 bit Virtual Machine (VMWare). Now I want to establish remote debugging. 
I can establish a connection and attach to an existing process (for example firefox).

But when I try to start my very simple project , I get the error "The visual studio remote debugger does not support this edition of windows".

I switched off authentification of the remote debugger.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get the answer to this problem ?